# Archive page uri format

Tags: wordpress

I have the default URI format for WordPress archives like `%year%/%month%` and all of my posts are on the `/blog` page.

I want to put all archives also under `/blog`. How can I do this?

I have a category `\blog` that is the default category for all blog posts with post type `post` and I have other types of posts.

How can I put my archive in the `blog/%year%/%month%` format?

**Current situation:** To retrieve archived posts page, access `%year%/%month%` URI

**Desired situation:** To retrieve archived posts page, access `blog/%year%/%month%` URI